# From elastic to fragile chocolate

Tags: chocolate

I tried to make a homemade chocolate by mixing

```
coco powder (5 teaspoon)
milk powder (3/4 cup)
butter (1/4 cup)
sugar syrap (1/4 cup sugar) [to completely dissolve the sugar particles]
```

the resulting chocolate was quite good but too elastic. I am curious what in the ingredients (or the procedure) controls the chocolate structure to become elastic or fragile?

How to play with the ingredients and process to prepare different types of (simple and basic) chocolate?

Comment: This sounds like what's called *házi csoki* ("homemade chocolate") in Hungarian: a confection made with cocoa powder, sugar, butter/margarine, and a fairly large proportion of powdered milk. It was popular when Communism made actual chocolate impossible to obtain. It's best to think of it as a type of fudge, though: it doesn't, and is not meant to, actually imitate all the properties of chocolate.

Comment: Actually, I wonder if simple dehydration of the finished confection might make it a touch more fragile, by removing some or all of the water from the syrup and butter which would keep it moist and thus softer.  Thinner pieces would, I think, both dry quicker and tend towards brittle or fragile rather than simply hard.

Answer (score 6):

It is not really practical to make homemade chocolate, although you can make chocolate flavored confections like syrups or fudge.

The reason is that true chocolate has two main ingredients:  cocoa butter (the fat native to the cocoa bean), and the cocoa powder (which is is made by taking cocoa mass and pressing out the cocoa butter).  Sweetened chocolate then has sugar, perhaps vanilla and salt, and usually lecithin added.

In order to have the right consistency (hardness) and melting characteristics, your fat would absolutely have to be cocoa butter.  No other fat has the unique crystallization characteristics or melting point that cocoa butter does.  It is possible to buy cocoa butter, although it is expensive.

The problem is that cocoa powder is not ground very fine, so the product will be gritty on the tongue and not have the same accessibility of flavor.   In true chocolate manufacturing, specialized devices called *conches* are used to grind the cocoa particles down to very small size, to the point where they cannot be felt on the tongue; this is what gives chocolate its characteristic smooth texture together with the cocoa butter.

Conching is not practical in the home.

Your best, and most likely most cost effective bet is to simply purchase chocolate.

Comment: Actually, I am quite satisfied by  the taste, I just want to make it more fragile. Your answer clarified the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Butter has a lower melting point than cocoa butter (and also softens at lower temperatures than it melts at), which would make your chocolate much softer than normal chocolate. Also, the syrup would have a softening effect on the finished product. Sugar syrups are frequently added to ganache to make it more pliable when set.

To make a better "chocolate", you'd need a fat with a higher melting point and less liquid in your recipe.

Comment: Using less liquid might mean using a much dryer syrup, (heated to candy-making temps, perhaps, so most of the water is gone) or it might mean using actual sugar instead of syrup, in which case an equivalent amount of confectioner's sugar might give a smoother end result, since the sugar won't have anything to dissolve in.

Comment: @megha I think a syrup heated to candymaking temperatures would scald the chocolate.

Comment: Yes, I suppose it might, though using cocoa powder instead of actual chocolate might make a difference there, I'm not sure.  Or perhaps one might heat the syrup, but wait for it to cool to more workable temps before mixing the rest of the ingredients.  I'm just not sure how else to reduce or remove an appreciable amount of the water, if the sugar was dissolved into syrup first.  Not dissolving the sugar at all is another choice, of course, but one that will leave the sugar crystals intact to affect texture.

Comment: @megha true. I think it'd be something more like fudge than chocolate, but that's probably unavoidable with these conditions