# How do I make my own chocolate chips?

Tags: chocolate, candy, melting-chocolate

I'd love to make my own chocolate chips from scratch.  But everything I've produced seems to melt during cooking.  It would be nice to make them based on the **percentage of coco** I like and it would be fantastic to make **sugar-free** chocolate chips for some diabetic friends.  Any suggestions?

What I need is a recipe for making chocolate chips that I can bake with.

**Update:**

I now have a family member that is soy-intolerant.  Most chocolate chips and chocolates that can be chopped up have soy-lecithin in them.

So I still have this problem.  I'd like to make a **sugar-free**, **soy-free** "chocolate chip" for my family.  It doesn't have to be teardrop shaped or look pretty, that was never a goal.

So my question is still:  How can I make a chocolate product at home that can be broken into pieces and used like chocolate chips.  It makes sense to buy **pure** chocolate that has already gone through the conche process.  What should be done then?  What is the recipe to change the pure chocolate into something that has coco-butter, sweetner etc.

Comment: See related:  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/36645/from-elastic-to-fragile-chocolate  It is not practical to make chocolate at home.

Comment: Hello Maelish, I just read through the existing answer and your update. I fail to see what you are looking for which is not covered in the answer? It doesn't say what not to do, it tells you what to do: buy the chocolate you want and break it into pieces.

Comment: Agreed: there's really not much to do here besides buy chocolate and chop it up. If you still really want to know "how do I add sugar to existing pure chocolate?" that's a new question and you should post it as one.

Comment: Pure chocolate already consists of cocoa butter,  sweetener and cocoa solids. You don't have to add anything to it to make chocolate chips. The only difference between chocolate chips and chocolate bars is the shape. All you have to do is to chop the bar up. And that's what the answer says.

Answer (score 2):

Chocolate chips are a convenience product meant to simulate chopped up chocolate.  Your best bet is to find the chocolate that you like, and chop it.

If you really want the droplet shape, you would need to temper the chocolate, and then pipe it into little droplets which would be incredibly tedious, and almost certainly not worth the effort.

Comment: piping isn't that tedious, once you get the hang of it ... I would think the issue would be working fast enough so it didn't sieze up on you and you had to re-temper it.

Comment: I assume the OP is looking for the droplet shape for aesthetic reasons. While I agree with you, maybe there is a handy way to recreate this form in the home kitchen?

Comment: @PrestonFitzgerald Absolutely there is.  Melt, optionally temper, and pipe chocolate.  Or even use a squeeze bottle.

Comment: No I am not looking for the droplet shape in particular.  What I need is a recipe for making chocolate `chips` that I can bake with.

Comment: @Maelish Yes, chop up chocolate.  That is what you want.

Comment: Nope.  I want to control the amount of coco and sugar in each chip.  You guys are missing the point.

Comment: Chocolate chips are *just chocolate* (at least the quality ones are), and that is not something you can practically make at home.  You control the percentage of chocolate and sugar by selection of the chocolate you use, not by creating your own chocolate.  You could conceivably melt together two different chocolates, to get a blending of their levels of cocoa and sugar, but then you would be back to needing to temper.

Comment: @Maelish If you want to control the amount of cocoa and sugar in each chip, just find a chocolate with the proportions you want and chop it. As has been pointed out, chocolate making is a whole elaborate process that can't easily be done at home.